# Update table but use a value from column - select case

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Not sure if this is possible, but I have a field in a table which needs to be updated by a value from another table, but references a specific column e.g. if it's 1 then get the value out of the `[Jan]` column etc.

```
Update table1
    Set Total = 
        CASE @count
            WHEN 1  THEN [Jan]
            WHEN 2  THEN [Feb]
            WHEN 3  THEN [Mar]
            WHEN 4  THEN [Apr]
            WHEN 5  THEN [May]
            WHEN 6  THEN [Jun]
            WHEN 7  THEN [Jul]
            WHEN 8  THEN [Aug]
            WHEN 9  THEN [Sep]
            WHEN 10 THEN [Oct]
            WHEN 11 THEN [Nov]
            WHEN 12 THEN [Dec]
        END
    from table2
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried it (seeing as you've written it)?  I think it should work.

Comment: why is count declared a variable ? How should the tables be joined ? Do you have any test data and expected results ? Btw Paddy - answer is no, it does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Update t
    Set t.Total = 
        CASE @count
            WHEN 1  THEN t2.[Jan]
            WHEN 2  THEN t2.[Feb]
            WHEN 3  THEN t2.[Mar]
            WHEN 4  THEN t2.[Apr]
            WHEN 5  THEN t2.[May]
            WHEN 6  THEN t2.[Jun]
            WHEN 7  THEN t2.[Jul]
            WHEN 8  THEN t2.[Aug]
            WHEN 9  THEN t2.[Sep]
            WHEN 10 THEN t2.[Oct]
            WHEN 11 THEN t2.[Nov]
            WHEN 12 THEN t2.[Dec]
        END
    from table1 t inner join table2 t2 
    on t.ID = t2.ID --your condition
```

Comment: Cheers Vikram, that works perfectly, it's nice to know I wasn't too far away

Answer (score 3):

You could put the `CASE` in a sub-query:

```
UPDATE table1
SET Total=(SELECT TOP 1 CASE @count
            WHEN 1  THEN [Jan]
            WHEN 2  THEN [Feb]
            WHEN 3  THEN [Mar]
            WHEN 4  THEN [Apr]
            WHEN 5  THEN [May]
            WHEN 6  THEN [Jun]
            WHEN 7  THEN [Jul]
            WHEN 8  THEN [Aug]
            WHEN 9  THEN [Sep]
            WHEN 10 THEN [Oct]
            WHEN 11 THEN [Nov]
            WHEN 12 THEN [Dec]
        END
        FROM table2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNPIVOT` for this.

```
UPDATE Table2
SET [Total] =
(
    SELECT B.[Total]
    FROM
    (
        SELECT [Jan], [Feb], [Mar], [Apr], [May], [Jun]
             , [Jul], [Aug], [Sep], [Oct], [Nov], [Dec]
        FROM Table2
    ) AS A ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]
          , [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12])
    UNPIVOT ([Total] FOR [Month] IN
           ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]
          , [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12])) B
    WHERE B.[Month] = @count
)
```